# iPhone 4 died and need to know how to retrieve data on flashed phone

Tags: ios, icloud, backup, restore

My iPhone 4 completely died. I got one of my fathers old iPhone 4's and had it flashed at Cleartalk. How can I retrieve all of my data that was backed up on the icloud?

Answer (score 0):

Did you open iCloud on the iPhone 4 and backup your data there? If so, it is pretty easy. Just enter your icloud on your father's old phone using the same Apple account, download data to it, things done.

Comment: Unfortunately no, my phone shut off on Sunday and never came back on so I did not get a chance to do that. But I had the auto back up option on so I'm not sure if that's the same thing. When Cleartalk flashed my dad's phone to my number they basically jailbreak it and had it all set up for me when I picked it up so I never got the option to restore icloud back up. :(